# R long-table to multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: r, data.table, transform

I have a table in the long format:

```
require(data.table)
sampleDT <- data.table(Old = c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B")
                       , New = c("A","A","B","B","A","A","B","B")
                       , Time = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
                       , value1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
                       , value2 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
print(sampleDT)

   Old New Time value1 value2
1:   A   A    1      1      0
2:   B   A    1      1      0
3:   A   B    1      1      0
4:   B   B    1      1      0
5:   A   A    2      1      0
6:   B   A    2      1      0
7:   A   B    2      1      0
8:   B   B    2      1      0
```

I would like to convert to an array of 3 dimensions. Something like:
[image]

Basically, we would have columns "New, Old, Time" as our three dimensions.
And the value for each cell is an output of some sort of functions whose input are "value1, value2".

In this case, when `Time = 1`, the result is:

```
matrix(data = c(1, 1+0, 0, -0), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = FALSE)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    1    0
```

How to achieve it?

Memory usage and computing time are important considerations, as we're working on relatively big datasets.

Comment: how r u going to use the 3d array after this? it might be more efficient to keep your data in a relational format

Comment: It seems like you are conflating two problems: (1) calculating the values to go in the array, and (2) generating the array structure. `data.table` is highly optimized, so I think you can compute whatever values you want to go in the array, call them `v`, and then `reshape2::acast(sampleDT[, .(Old, New, Time, v)], Old ~ New ~ Time, value.var = "v")`. There may be more efficiency using the `abind` package or `array()` directly, but I don't see any reason to include the computation based on "some sort of functions" in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try xtabs():

```
sampleDT <- data.frame(Old = c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B"), 
                       New = c("A","A","B","B","A","A","B","B"),
                       Time = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                       value1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                       value2 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))

Value1 <- xtabs(value1 ~ Old + New + Time, sampleDT, drop = FALSE)
Value2 <- xtabs(value2 ~ Old + New + Time, sampleDT, drop = FALSE)

is.array(Value1)
is.array(Value2)

Value1[, 2,] <- 0 # Sets all second columns to zero for Value1
Value2[1,,] <- 0 # Idem with first row for Value2
Value2[2,2,] <- Value2[2,2,] * (-1)

Result <- Value1 + Value2

Result

, , Time = 1

   New
Old A B
  A 1 0
  B 1 0

, , Time = 2

   New
Old A B
  A 1 0
  B 1 0
```

Hope it helps.